# Need to Export Wikipages to txt

Tags: sharepoint, wiki, export, txt-record

Need to export my sharepoint wikipages to txt, is this possible? If, how? Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](https://tlt.stonybrook.edu/FacultyServices/Software/Documents/Export_SharePoint_Wiki.pdf) an in-depth description on how to export all your Sharepoint wiki pages to PDF or Word. The trick is to create a printer friendy view of all the pages. From either PDF or Word you can then convert them to text by copy & paste. You will lose some of the formatting and all links.

If you are planning to import the pages to another Sharepoint then I guess the [stsadm tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766807.aspx) would be a better choice.